# Pandas: .tolist() provides float number

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to execute a simple code using pandas. The purpose of this function is to read the excel file, select specific columns value, and print as a list. All the values are integer but after execution, it converted to float numbers. How to solve this!

```
import pandas as pd

def read_xlsx():
    df = pd.read_excel('pc.xlsx')
    return df['Gtin'].values.tolist()
```

## output

```
[nan, 5010533606001.0, 190017004495.0, 190017036816.0, 190017063614.0, 190017072685.0, 190017116853.0, 190017116891.0, 190017116914.0, 190017140742.0, 190017140766.0, 190017140780.0, 190017140803.0, 190017199764.0, 190781971054.0, 191628982509.0, 192545088695.0, 619659155193.0, 619659155438.0, 619659155476.0, 643653640010.0, 643653640027.0, 672042080908.0, 672042135455.0, 672042152414.0, 672042156689.0, 672042154012.0, 672042162406.0, 672042194063.0, 672042197422.0, 672042197507.0, 672042222278.0, 672042227198.0, 672042269068.0, 672042280032.0, 672042287680.0, 672042318629.0, 675901510417.0]
```

Comment: That's not additional, that means the value is float.

Comment: I know this is a float value. Sorry for using non relevant words. I'll definitely take care of it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the float representation, if you want the numbers as integer, you need to first drop `NaN` values, then convert to integer, finally get the list:

```py
def read_xlsx():
    df = pd.read_excel('pc.xlsx')
    return df['Gtin'].dropna().astype('int64').tolist()
```

#### OUTPUT:

```py
[5010533606001, 190017004495, 190017036816, 190017063614, 190017072685, 190017116853, 190017116891, 190017116914, 190017140742, 190017140766, 190017140780, 190017140803, 190017199764, 190781971054, 191628982509, 192545088695, 619659155193, 619659155438, 619659155476, 643653640010, 643653640027, 672042080908, 672042135455, 672042152414, 672042156689, 672042154012, 672042162406, 672042194063, 672042197422, 672042197507, 672042222278, 672042227198, 672042269068, 672042280032, 672042287680, 672042318629, 675901510417]
```

Comment: Pandas has Support for missing values in integer colums since pandas 1.0, no need to drop them. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html

Comment: Yeah, it has `<NA>` to represent `NaN` as integer, but I don't think OP is interested in `NaN` values. Additionally, converting to int keeping `NaN` requires pandas IntDtypes to be used.

Answer (score 1):

The missing value i.e `NAN` is dictating the type of list as float, which is why it is converted to a float with .0 at the end of each number. If you remove this `NAN` before converting it to a list and set the type to an int as shown below, you will get the expected results:

```
def read_xlsx():
    df = pd.read_excel('pc.xlsx').dropna.astype(int)
    return df['Gtin'].values.tolist()
```